# Search biggest space in 2d array

Tags: c#, algorithm

[image: Screen shot]

I have random color generator. As you can see in photo it randomly generates a color (R - red, G - green, Y - yellow).

I need to find which color takes up the biggest space. But there is one condition. I can count the biggest space for that color which have a lot of same neighbor. I don't know how to say it, English is not my main language.

For example, RGYRGYRGRGRGRGRGR  red does not takes up the biggest space because it is separate from each other. But RRRRRRRRGYGYG is good, because all R colors are near.

How can I do it? At first I thought that I need to use breadth-first search algorithm. But my professor said that I can "scan" rows or columns. So I don't know how to do it. Which way would be the easiest?

Comment: Space, meaning in a row or row*column (a vertical column will also count as Biggest) ?

Comment: what do you mean by space? are only "rows" of the same color important, or is it rectangles that are more important? or any connected area? even non-convex? what you are after most likely is an application of union-find algorithm described at many places, such as here http://vancexu.github.io/2015/07/21/intro-to-union-find-data-structure-exercise.html

Comment: I need to find the biggest blob of adjacent same-colored elements

Answer (score 5):

Are you trying to find the biggest blob of adjacent same-colored elements? In that case, something like the opposite of a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill might be easiest. Start from each position and see how far you can get before you reach the boundaries. Places that you've already added from a previous "fill" don't need to be checked again.

Comment: Yes, I need to find the biggest blob of adjacent same-colored elements

Comment: This is how I would approach it as well

Comment: 'But my professor said that I can "scan" rows or columns' makes me worry that there's some clever algorithm being sought.

Comment: You could do it with a scan, but the state information needed to do it would be excessively complicated. This is probably the best algorithmic approach.

Answer (score 2):

There are [connected-component labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) algorithms, they are intended to solve such kind of problems.
Wiki page is devoted mainly to binary case, but algorithm implementations exist also for blob extraction from multi-color pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm I wrote months ago, which was written in C, I am gonna translate into C# if I have time.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int find_root(int index, int *roots) {
    // index = i * height + j
    if (roots[index] == index) return index;
    else {
        int root = find_root(roots[index], roots);
        roots[index] = root;
        return root;
    }
}

void process(char matrix[], long width, long height) {

    long number_of_pixels = height * width;

    int *roots = (int *)malloc(number_of_pixels * sizeof(int));
    // roots[width * i + j] points the root of area where i, j belongs to

    int *connectivities = (int *)malloc(number_of_pixels * sizeof(int)); 
    // connectivities explain:
    // 1  -> isolated, 
    // 0  -> non-isolated, non-root, 
    // >1 -> non-isolated, root

    // only consider left and upper sides!!!
    const int connects[2][2] = {
        {-1, 0},
        {0, -1}
    };

    for (long i = 0; i < number_of_pixels; ++i) {
        roots[i] = i;
        connectivities[i] = 1;
    }

    for (long i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        for (long j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 2; ++k) {
                long neighbor_j = j + connects[k][0];
                long neighbor_i = i + connects[k][1];
                if (neighbor_j >= 0 && neighbor_j < width
                    && neighbor_i >= 0 && neighbor_i < height
                    && matrix[width * neighbor_i + neighbor_j] == matrix[width * i + j]) {
                    // join it to neighbor group
                    long root = find_root(i * width + j, roots);
                    long neighbor_root 
                        = find_root(width * neighbor_i + neighbor_j, roots);
                    if (root == neighbor_root) continue;
                    roots[root] = neighbor_root;
                    connectivities[neighbor_root] += connectivities[root];
                    connectivities[root] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Now we gonna print the root of area each point belongs to
    for (long i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        for (long j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
            long index = i * width + j;
            printf("%3d", find_root(index, roots));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Now we gonna print the space of area each point belongs to
    for (long i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        for (long j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
            long index = i * width + j;
            printf("%3d", connectivities[find_root(index, roots)]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(connectivities);
    free(roots);
}

int main() {
    char mat[] = "YYYYYYYYYRGYRGYRGRGRGRGRGR"
                 "YYYYYYYYYRGYRGYRGRGRGRGRGR"
                 "YYYYYYYYRGYRGYRGRGRGRGRGRY";
    int width = 26;
    int height = 3;
    for (long i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        for (long j = 0; j < width; ++j) {
            long index = i * width + j;
            printf("  %c", mat[index]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    process(mat, width, height);
}
```

The output is:

```
  Y  Y  Y  Y  Y  Y  Y  Y  Y  R  G  Y  R  G  Y  R  G  R  G  R  G  R  G  R  G  R
  Y  Y  Y  Y  Y  Y  Y  Y  Y  R  G  Y  R  G  Y  R  G  R  G  R  G  R  G  R  G  R
  Y  Y  Y  Y  Y  Y  Y  Y  R  G  Y  R  G  Y  R  G  R  G  R  G  R  G  R  G  R  Y
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77
 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Basically, it will save the space into the connectivity array. And this algorithm requires you scan only once.